# Need today's date as default value in a form field in Libre Office

Tags: libreoffice, date, libreoffice-base

New to Libre Office Base.

I've found how to set the default value in a table to the current date. Now I need to have the current date show up in the corresponding field in a form.

I have tried inserting into "default value" `TODAY()` and `CURRENT_DATE`.  They both give me Nov. 18, 1899 for some reason.

Anyone have any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

This macro writes the date of today to the Date Field `myDateField`:

```
Sub writeDate
    Dim today As New com.sun.star.util.Date
    today.Month = Month( Now )
    today.Day = Day( Now )
    today.Year = Year( Now )
    form = ThisComponent.DrawPage.Forms(0)  ' first form
    form.myDateField.BoundField.UpdateDate( today )
End Sub
```

To assign the action: Form Navigator > myForm > Form Properties > Events > e.g. When loading

Answer (score 2):

Use the following macro code.  Here, the table's column (not the control name) is called "MyDate".

```vb
Sub DefaultDateInForm (oEvent As Object)
    oForm = oEvent.Source
    lDateCol = oForm.findColumn("MyDate")
    If oForm.getString(lDateCol) = "" Then
        dateStamp = Format(Now, "YYYY-MM-DD")
        oForm.updateString(lDateCol, dateStamp)
    End If
End Sub
```

Edit the form, and in form properties, assign the macro to the "after record change" event.

[image: form properties]

Now, whenever a record's date is empty, such as when a new record is started, the date field should default to the current date.

There are several discussions about this topic on the openoffice forum:

- https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=19140
- https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=39&t=38005
- https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=39&t=75991
- https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=39&t=131

Comment: Thanks, but not much progress.  Now I'm getting 25 Dec 1899.  Hey, at least it's Christmas!  Will check out your links.

Comment: Perhaps there is something different about your system's date settings, or the control?  It worked on my machine.  Try changing `"YYYY-MM-DD"` to a different format -- does it literally say "Dec. 25, 1899" in the date control?  Mine shows the format "02/01/17".  To find the problem, it may help to `MsgBox(dateStamp)` and `MsgBox(oForm.getString(lDateCol))`.

Comment: Well, no matter how I format it, it is that date.  Well, as I try a few different things, it changes.  Actually got 1 Jan 0002 once and a few other weird ones.  I'm new at this.  Don't know what you mean by MsgBox().  But thanks!

Comment: uh-oh.  Now I'm getting an error box, "Error inserting the new record / java.lang.IllegalArgumentException"

Comment: For example, add `MsgBox(dateStamp)` on the next line after `dateStamp = Format(Now, "YYYY-MM-DD")`.  The error may indicate that the format isn't right yet.

Comment: Join this chat room and hopefully we can figure out the problem: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52946/superuser-question-1174199

Answer (score 1):

From [Jim K’s answer](https://superuser.com/a/1174368/167207):

- discussions about this topic on the openoffice forum: https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?p=495533&sid=1543d4682d62ce59fc2850853366b38a#p495533):

> Without any macro you can define the current date as default value for the table. It is inserted when you save a new record with the date missing.

- menu:Tools -> SQL...

```sql
ALTER TABLE "tbl" ALTER COLUMN "col" DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE
```

replace "tbl" and "col" with the actual names of table and column.
[Execute]

Checked and works perfectly:

[image]

Comment: Actually, the OP is asking for solution dealing with updating date field with CURRENT DATE right on the FORM not after adding a NEW RECORD in the TABLE.

Comment: Can someone pls tell me the code to set a form unbound Date Field control to the value of a ResultSet Date column? My idea is to have a form which has unbound "DateFrom"  and "DateTo" conrtrols. Then set the form date controls initial values to the value of my SystemParam default rpt from and to dates in the Form WhenLoading events, also allowing the date controls to be changed if required. Then when the button to run the rpt is clicked, set a boolean "Selected" column to true for records in the date range before running the report. Then the report only has to select rows where Selected = 1.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't you know it, I solved my problem shortly after asking for help.

Here is my solution for setting a default value from a database date column into an unbound date control. I'm sure there is a better way than using `oCol.String`, and I'd be glad to hear a better way.

```
Sub Form_WhenLoading

' Default control dteDateFrom to SystemParam.DfltRptFrDate
'     and control dteDateTo   to SystemParam.DfltRptToDate

dim oForm as object
dim oControl as object
dim oResultSet as object
dim oContext as object
dim oDB as object
dim oStmt as object
dim sSQL as string
dim oCol as object          ' Column of oResultSet
Dim aDate As New com.sun.star.util.Date

oForm = ThisComponent.DrawPage.Forms.getByIndex(0)
oController = ThisComponent.CurrentController   
oContext = CreateUnoService("com.sun.star.sdb.DatabaseContext")
oDb = oContext.getByName("DatabaseName")
oConn = oDb.getConnection("","")
 
sSQL = "SELECT ""DfltRptFrDate"", ""DfltRptToDate"" from ""SystemParam"" WHERE ""SystemKey"" = '0';"

oStmt = oConn.createStatement()
oResultSet = oStmt.executeQuery(sSQL)

If Not IsNull(oResultSet) Then
    oResultSet.next
End If

' dteDateFrom
oCol = oResultSet.Columns.getByName("DfltRptFrDate")
oControl = oForm.GetByName("dteDateFrom")

' OCol.String is YYYY-MM-DD
aDate.year = left(oCol.String, 4)
aDate.month = mid(oCol.String, 6,2)
aDate.day = right(oCol.String, 2)
If IsEmpty(oControl.Date) Then 
    oControl.Date = aDate
    oControl.text = oCol.String
    oControl.Commit()
End If

' dteDateTo
oCol = oResultSet.Columns.getByName("DfltRptToDate")
oControl = oForm.GetByName("dteDateTo")
aDate.year = left(oCol.String, 4)
aDate.month = mid(oCol.String, 6,2)
aDate.day = right(oCol.String, 2)
If IsEmpty(oControl.Date) Then 
    oControl.Date = aDate
    oControl.text = oCol.String
    oControl.Commit()
End If

End sub
```